# Generated email comes from a different IP address than the Virtual IP that the SSL certificate has assigned

Tags: email, ip, azure-web-app-service

I have created an Azure Website and registered an SSL certificate which gives me a Virtual IP (VIP) address. I then have some simple code that sends an email to our corporate mail server to relay the email on. To allow it to relay, it needs to trust the IP that the email is coming from which should be xx.xx.xxx.121. Unfortunately the IP is not the same as the VIP the site was given when registering the SSL certifcate and comes from xx.xx.xxx.171.

Does anyone know why this is the case or if there is a way to get my code running on the Azure website to use the VIP?

Thanks

Update: Microsoft have got back to me

The out going IP is not same with the VIP assigned. Please check out this document.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn175718.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the email can come from any IP in the data centre range. It looks like using queuing and picking off emails and sending internally is next best option.